# cant assign to operator using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSAA4.png)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

red-player = pygame.image.load('red.png')
blue-player = pygame.image.load('blue.png')

four = False

Answer (score 2):

`red-player` is parsed as "*subtract* `player` from `red`", and it's impossible to assign to an operator (the `__sub__` operator in this case), hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

hyphens are not valid identifier characters.

```
red-player = pygame.image.load('red.png')
```

is evaluated as:

```
red - player = pygame.image.load('red.png')
```

Which makes no sense.

Use an underscore instead.

```
red_player = pygame.image.load('red.png')
```